# Debian 9 LXQt: Required packages for minimal possible desktop installation?

Tags: debian, gui, desktop-environment, lxde, lxqt

I'm excited about very pure and slim desktop environments without unnecessary bloat. In the past I always installed Debian with `LXDE` as a minimal possible desktop installation considering only inevitably necessary packages to run the GUI like:

```
xserver-xorg-core
lxde-core
lightdm
network-manager
network-manager-gnome
```

---

Now I want to switch to Debian 9 with `LXQt`. Which packages are at least required for the minimal possible installation of the new `LXQt`-GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I just tried it by myself:** Only the package `lxqt-core` is necessary! This package already delivers required dependencies like display manager, window manager, file manager (`pcmanfm-qt`) and panel.

---

Furthermore it is recommendable to install `lxqt-qtplugin` as well, otherwise the symbol icons won't work proper...

Comment: PLEASE consider amending your answer to note that there is a big difference between ```apt-get install lxqt-core``` and ```apt-get --no-install-recommends lxqt-core```. For me, the difference is 71 packages, 18Mb downloads, and 169Mb disk space, but YMMV based upon what prior packages you had installed.

Comment: The keyboard and mouse did not work until I installed: xserver-xorg-input-libinput For what it is worth...

Answer (score 2):

You can install LXQT on debian stretch through the following commands:

```
apt install lxqt-core
apt install lxqt
apt install task-lxqt-desktop
```

[LXQt: The Lightweight Qt Desktop Environment](https://wiki.debian.org/LXQt)

You can get a minimal `LXQT` desktop by excluding the recommended packages:

```
apt --no-install-recommends install lxqt compton compton-conf
apt install sddm lxterminal
```

You can install your favorite [Web Browsers](https://wiki.debian.org/WebBrowsers) through `apt` ,also [`midori`](http://midori-browser.org/download/debian/) is a lightweight web browser packaged in debian repository.

Comment: I fear the package `lxqt` contains a whole bunch of bloatware. Even the developers themselves say: "There are metapackages `lxqt-core` providing core features and `lxqt` providing LXQt as a whole plus some additional applications." Like I mentioned before: I want to install all necessary applications by myself to avoid an undesired bloat. Can I install only the packages `lxqt-core` as well as `task-lxqt-desktop` to get a already working desktop environment? (Source: https://github.com/lxde/lxqt/wiki/Binary-packages)

Comment: @Dave answer edited including some details.

Comment: task-lxqt-desktop lists the lxqt metapackage as a dependency. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/task-lxqt-desktop. I would try, just, lxqt-core PLUS a browser e.g. Chromium and sound e.g. Pulseaudio. LightDM is Ok as a desktop login manager -  if you don't have it you will have to input startx

Comment: @arochester: "I would try, just, `lxqt-core`". You are completely right! One only need the packages `lxqt-core` as well as `lxqt-qtplugin` (otherwise the icons don't work reliable)... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

And keep in mind that lxqt and lxqt-core are meta-packages - if one don't like these one can install the needed components by hand - the meta-packages can and will be a good guide.